# Azure File Server / AD Server

Tags: windows, azure, windows-server-2016

We have 2 Windows 2016 Servers in Azure, one is currently setup as an Active Directory Server and File Server, the other just a test server. Both are connected to on Premise using a site to site IPSec VPN tunnel.

We have several shares on the AD server and we are finding that some shares are inaccessible.

So if I try and browse \Server\Share1 - I can access it fine.

However, If I try and access \Server\Share2 - I receive an error stating that:

```
"The specified network name is no longer available"
```

I should state that this is accessing the share over the VPN to on premise. If I was to access the share from the second Azure server its fine. Which made me think it was a VPN issue.

However, if I was to restart the server in question, then service is restored for a short while.

To also add to this, I am seeing errors in repadmin / showrepl command, stating that the RPC remote procedure call failed.

I moved some data to the other server and was able to access the shares fine.

We performed some packet capturing using Wireshark and at the time of accessing the file shares, I can see several TCP retransmissions. It seems as though the Azure server stops communicating with OnPrem, until the reboot is performed.

To add to this AD replication / DNS replication doesn't work until rebooted BUT udp communication works fine, ie DNS requests etc..

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: You state that one server is a DC and a file server and the other is a test server, but you mention replication. Is the other server also a DC? If not, any replication errors you're seeing on the DC can be ignored. A single DC doesn't replicate anything to any other server.

Comment: Sorry, wasn’t clear. The DC is replicating to a DC on Prem.